# Is there a way to make the return of GetConversationHeight not to be so slow?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If there are only 200 items in the reorderableList it's getting very slow.
Almost freezing the unity editor.

I got the answer in the time back here : [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56180821/how-can-i-use-reorderablelist-with-a-list-in-the-inspector-and-adding-new-empty)

I found that this part make it so slow :

```
elementHeightCallback = (index) =>
            {
                return GetConversationHeight(_conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index));
            }
```

This is the full code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ConversationTrigger))]
public class ConversationTriggerEditor : Editor
{
    private ConversationTrigger _conversationTrigger;

    [SerializeField] private ReorderableList conversationsList;

    private SerializedProperty _conversations;

    private int _currentlySelectedConversationIndex = -1;

    private readonly Dictionary<string, ReorderableList> _dialoguesListDict = new Dictionary<string, ReorderableList>();
    private readonly Dictionary<string, ReorderableList> _sentencesListDict = new Dictionary<string, ReorderableList>();

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _conversationTrigger = (ConversationTrigger)target;
        _conversations = serializedObject.FindProperty("conversations");

        conversationsList = new ReorderableList(serializedObject, _conversations)
        {
            displayAdd = true,
            displayRemove = true,
            draggable = true,

            drawHeaderCallback = DrawConversationsHeader,

            drawElementCallback = DrawConversationsElement,

            onAddCallback = (list) =>
            {
                SerializedProperty addedElement;
                // if something is selected add after that element otherwise on the end
                if (_currentlySelectedConversationIndex >= 0)
                {
                    list.serializedProperty.InsertArrayElementAtIndex(_currentlySelectedConversationIndex + 1);
                    addedElement = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(_currentlySelectedConversationIndex + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    list.serializedProperty.arraySize++;
                    addedElement = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(list.serializedProperty.arraySize - 1);
                }

                var name = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                var foldout = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");
                var dialogues = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Dialogues");

                name.stringValue = "";
                foldout.boolValue = true;
                dialogues.arraySize = 0;
            },

            elementHeightCallback = (index) =>
            {
                return GetConversationHeight(_conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index));
            }
        };
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();

        // if there are no elements reset _currentlySelectedConversationIndex
        if (conversationsList.serializedProperty.arraySize - 1 < _currentlySelectedConversationIndex) _currentlySelectedConversationIndex = -1;

        conversationsList.DoLayoutList();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Save Conversations"))
        {
            _conversationTrigger.SaveConversations();
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button("Load Conversations"))
        {
            Undo.RecordObject(_conversationTrigger, "Loaded conversations from JSON");
            _conversationTrigger.LoadConversations();
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();

        //Repaint();
    }

    #region Drawers

    #region List Headers

    private void DrawConversationsHeader(Rect rect)
    {
        EditorGUI.LabelField(rect, "Conversations");
    }

    private void DrawDialoguesHeader(Rect rect)
    {
        EditorGUI.LabelField(rect, "Dialogues");
    }

    private void DrawSentencesHeader(Rect rect)
    {
        EditorGUI.LabelField(rect, "Sentences");
    }

    #endregion List Headers

    #region Elements

    private void DrawConversationsElement(Rect rect, int index, bool isActive, bool isFocused)
    {
        if (isActive) _currentlySelectedConversationIndex = index;

        var conversation = _conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

        var position = new Rect(rect);

        var name = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
        var foldout = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");
        var dialogues = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("Dialogues");
        string dialoguesListKey = conversation.propertyPath;

        EditorGUI.indentLevel++;
        {
            // make the label be a foldout
            foldout.boolValue = EditorGUI.Foldout(new Rect(position.x, position.y, 10, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), foldout.boolValue, foldout.boolValue ? "" : name.stringValue);

            if (foldout.boolValue)
            {
                // draw the name field
                name.stringValue = EditorGUI.TextField(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), name.stringValue);
                position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

                if (!_dialoguesListDict.ContainsKey(dialoguesListKey))
                {
                    // create reorderabl list and store it in dict
                    var dialoguesList = new ReorderableList(conversation.serializedObject, dialogues)
                    {
                        displayAdd = true,
                        displayRemove = true,
                        draggable = true,

                        drawHeaderCallback = DrawDialoguesHeader,

                        drawElementCallback = (convRect, convIndex, convActive, convFocused) => { DrawDialoguesElement(_dialoguesListDict[dialoguesListKey], convRect, convIndex, convActive, convFocused); },

                        elementHeightCallback = (dialogIndex) =>
                        {
                            return GetDialogueHeight(_dialoguesListDict[dialoguesListKey].serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(dialogIndex));
                        },

                        onAddCallback = (list) =>
                        {
                            list.serializedProperty.arraySize++;
                            var addedElement = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(list.serializedProperty.arraySize - 1);

                            var newDialoguesName = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                            var newDialoguesFoldout = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");
                            var sentences = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Sentences");

                            newDialoguesName.stringValue = "";
                            newDialoguesFoldout.boolValue = true;
                            sentences.arraySize = 0;
                        }
                    };
                    _dialoguesListDict[dialoguesListKey] = dialoguesList;
                }

                _dialoguesListDict[dialoguesListKey].DoList(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, position.height - EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight));
            }

        }
        EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
    }

    private void DrawDialoguesElement(ReorderableList list, Rect rect, int index, bool isActive, bool isFocused)
    {
        if (list == null) return;

        var dialog = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

        var position = new Rect(rect);

        var foldout = dialog.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");
        var name = dialog.FindPropertyRelative("Name");

        {
            // make the label be a foldout
            foldout.boolValue = EditorGUI.Foldout(new Rect(position.x, position.y, 10, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), foldout.boolValue, foldout.boolValue ? "" : name.stringValue);

            var sentencesListKey = dialog.propertyPath;
            var sentences = dialog.FindPropertyRelative("Sentences");

            if (foldout.boolValue)
            {
                // draw the name field
                name.stringValue = EditorGUI.TextField(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), name.stringValue);
                position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

                if (!_sentencesListDict.ContainsKey(sentencesListKey))
                {
                    // create reorderabl list and store it in dict
                    var sentencesList = new ReorderableList(sentences.serializedObject, sentences)
                    {
                        displayAdd = true,
                        displayRemove = true,
                        draggable = true,

                        // header for the dialog list
                        drawHeaderCallback = DrawSentencesHeader,

                        // how a sentence is displayed
                        drawElementCallback = (sentenceRect, sentenceIndex, sentenceIsActive, sentenceIsFocused) =>
                        {
                            var sentence = sentences.GetArrayElementAtIndex(sentenceIndex);

                            // draw simple textArea for sentence
                            sentence.stringValue = EditorGUI.TextArea(sentenceRect, sentence.stringValue);
                        },

                        // Sentences have simply a fixed height of 2 lines
                        elementHeight = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 2,

                        // when a sentence is added
                        onAddCallback = (sentList) =>
                        {
                            sentList.serializedProperty.arraySize++;
                            var addedElement = sentList.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(sentList.serializedProperty.arraySize - 1);

                            addedElement.stringValue = "";
                        }
                    };

                    // store the created ReorderableList
                    _sentencesListDict[sentencesListKey] = sentencesList;
                }

                // Draw the list
                _sentencesListDict[sentencesListKey].DoList(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, position.height - EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight));
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion Elements

    #endregion Drawers


    #region Helpers

    #region HeightGetter

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the height of given Conversation property
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="conversation"></param>
    /// <returns>height of given Conversation property</returns>
    private float GetConversationHeight(SerializedProperty conversation)
    {
        var foldout = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");

        // if not foldout the height is simply 1 line
        var height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

        // otherwise we sum up every controls and child heights
        if (foldout.boolValue)
        {
            // we need some more lines:
            //  for the Name field,
            // the list header,
            // the list buttons and a bit buffer
            height += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 5;


            var dialogues = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("Dialogues");

            for (var d = 0; d < dialogues.arraySize; d++)
            {
                var dialog = dialogues.GetArrayElementAtIndex(d);
                height += GetDialogueHeight(dialog);
            }
        }

        return height;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the height of given Dialogue property
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dialog"></param>
    /// <returns>height of given Dialogue property</returns>
    private float GetDialogueHeight(SerializedProperty dialog)
    {
        var foldout = dialog.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");

        // same game for the dialog if not foldout it is only a single line
        var height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

        // otherwise sum up controls and child heights
        if (foldout.boolValue)
        {
            // we need some more lines:
            //  for the Name field,
            // the list header,
            // the list buttons and a bit buffer
            height += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 4;

            var sentences = dialog.FindPropertyRelative("Sentences");

            // the sentences are easier since they always have the same height
            // in this example 2 lines so simply do
            // at least have space for 1 sentences even if there is none
            height += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * Mathf.Max(1, sentences.arraySize) * 2;
        }

        return height;
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion Helpers
}
```

And this is the new code I got in my latest answer it looks I think better visual but it's not including the childs dialogues and sentences for each conversation :

In this code there are also 200 items but it's scrolling and moving smooth and fast :

```
private Vector2 scrollPos;
    private SerializedProperty conversations;
    private ConversationTrigger conversationTrigger;
    private ReorderableList conversationList;
    private int newSize = 0;

    private readonly Dictionary<string, ReorderableList> _dialoguesListDict = new Dictionary<string, ReorderableList>();
    private readonly Dictionary<string, ReorderableList> _sentencesListDict = new Dictionary<string, ReorderableList>();

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        conversations = serializedObject.FindProperty("conversations");
        conversationTrigger = (ConversationTrigger)target;        

        conversationList = new ReorderableList(serializedObject, conversations)
        {
            displayAdd = false,
            displayRemove = false,
            draggable = true,

            onAddCallback = list =>
            {
                // first add one element
                conversations.arraySize++;
                // then get that element
                var newIndex = conversations.arraySize - 1;
                var newElement = conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(newIndex);

                // now reset all properties like
                 var name = newElement.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                var foldout = newElement.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");
                var dialogues = newElement.FindPropertyRelative("Dialogues");

                name.stringValue = "";
                foldout.boolValue = true;
                dialogues.arraySize = 0;

                // ...
            },

            drawHeaderCallback = rect =>
            {

                /*EditorGUI.LabelField(new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, 100, rect.height), "Conversations", EditorStyles.boldLabel);

                var newSize = EditorGUI.IntField(new Rect(rect.x + 100, rect.y, rect.width - 100, rect.height), conversations.arraySize);

                conversations.arraySize = Mathf.Max(0, newSize);*/
            },

            drawElementCallback = (rect, index, isActive, isSelected) =>
            {
                var element = conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

                var name = element.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                // do this for all properties

                var position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(rect, new GUIContent(name.stringValue));

                EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, name);
            },

            elementHeight = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight
        };
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        // Load the current values from the real component into the serialized copy
        serializedObject.Update();

        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Conversations", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        {
            newSize = EditorGUILayout.IntField(conversations.arraySize);
        }
        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            if (newSize > conversations.arraySize)
            {
                // elements have to be added -> how many?
                var toAdd = newSize - conversations.arraySize - 1;
                // why -1 ? -> We add the first element and set its values to default
                // now if we simply increase the arraySize for the rest of the elements
                // they will be all a copy of the first -> all defaults ;)

                // first add one element
                conversations.arraySize++;
                // then get that element
                var newIndex = conversations.arraySize - 1;
                var newElement = conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(newIndex);

                // now reset all properties like
                var name = newElement.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                name.stringValue = "";

                // now for the rest simply increase arraySize
                conversations.arraySize += toAdd;
            }
            else
            {
                // for removing just make sure the arraySize is not under 0
                conversations.arraySize = Mathf.Max(newSize, 0);
            }
        }

        scrollPos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Height(250));

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        conversationList.DoLayoutList();

        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Add new conversation"))
        {
            // first add one element
            conversations.arraySize++;
            // then get that element
            var newIndex = conversations.arraySize - 1;
            var newElement = conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(newIndex);

            // now reset all properties like
            var name = newElement.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
            name.stringValue = "";
        }

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        if (conversations.arraySize != 0)
        {
            if (GUILayout.Button("Remove conversation"))
            {
                if (conversations.arraySize > 0) conversations.arraySize--;
            }
        }

        GUILayout.Space(100);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Save Conversations"))
        {
            conversationTrigger.SaveConversations();
        }

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Load Conversations"))
        {
            Undo.RecordObject(conversationTrigger, "Loaded conversations from JSON");
            conversationTrigger.LoadConversations();
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
```

My problems is how to combine the first answer code with the second answer code make it looks visual like the second one and to work fast and smooth with the dialogues and sentences if there are 200 items in the reorderableList.

Or maybe 100-150 items but for now the first answer code the part that get the ConversationHeight make the editor too slow almost freezing.

Comment: Your second code has a `/**/` comment that is never closed

Comment: I don't know much about editor scripting but maybe there's a way to cache the height of each dialogue so the height calculation can be done only when necessary